# Append big CSV files with some filtering, on Windows

Tags: windows, csv

Hi i've a very big csv file (more than 1,000,000 rows, 872.319 KB).
I need to open and add some other rows from another file also csv.
Which is the best solution. I tried ACCESS/VBA but freeze and also excel cannot open it. Web? or other software?

Comment: Do you need to add the rows of the second file at the bottom of the first file? Does the second file have a CSV header line?

Comment: How big is the second file?

Comment: second file is about 192.124Kb with 350,000 i need to filter only some rows with a critere and then append at the end of the big file. All files have headers and many columns about 161

Comment: It is super easy on Linux. Is that OK? If you want to restrict the question to a particular OS, please add a tag.

Comment: Now I use Windows...

Comment: Maybe Python with Pandas data analysis library? Thx